# Removing lines between two values in Highchart's line chart

Tags: highcharts

I have an ordinary line chart filled with weekly data from a table. Some weeks have no data but these instances are not marked with `null` or `0`.

The table can look something like this:

```
201734  45
201735  63
201738  68
201739  53
201740  76
```

So have this:
[image: bad chart]

As you can see it's impossible to see that there are missing weeks between week 35 and 38.

I want it to look like this:
[image: good chart]

where the line between two values have been erased when the difference between two weeks are not 1: `201738 - 201735 != 1`

My code looks similar to: https://jsfiddle.net/eumLdkjb/1/

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `categotries` array inside xAxis with missing names along with the `breaks`.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.categories
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.breaks

Example:
https://jsfiddle.net/1nz4kcum/

Comment: Yeah, that might work. I'll give it a try! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create array in a such a way that, y axis value will be null, for example current case:

```
['201736', null],['201737', null]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vsj5jmnz/

Comment: I still want the distance between the two values to be the same and not like here where the distance is longer because of the missing values. I also can't edit the data I get...